# Core Data Crash - NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification: attempt to insert nil with userInfo

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

When I try to insert series of Data using CoreData, it randomly crashes with this error message:

```
2019-04-03 17:24:31.217510+0530 YOUR APP[8862:401750] [error] error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
2019-04-03 17:24:31.223609+0530 YOUR APP[8862:401750] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107c371bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001071dd735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107c37015 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107c128da -[__NSCFSet addObject:] + 202
    4   CoreData                            0x00000001068cbb2b -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processPendingUpdates:] + 379
    5   CoreData                            0x00000001068c632b -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 1163
    6   CoreData                            0x000000010689ee8a _performRunLoopAction + 394
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b9bc27 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b960be __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b96751 __CFRunLoopRun + 1537
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b95e11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011160a1dd GSEventRunModal + 62
    12  UIKitCore                           0x000000010c90a81d UIApplicationMain + 140
    13  YOUR APP                            0x0000000104e23031 main + 225
    14  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b419575 start + 1
    15  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I am not able to figure out the reason behind the crash, but this crash happens 1/3 times the Insert/Retrieve happens in core data.

Please find the code below

```
public func insertUser(userList: [user], completion : (Bool) -> ()){
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        do {
            let userEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User_Table", in: context)

            for user in userList {
                let userBrandName = NSManagedObject(entity: userEntity!, insertInto: context)

                userBrandName.setValue(id, forKey: "Identity")
                userBrandName.setValue(name, forKey: "Name")
.....
                userBrandName.setValue(discount, forKey: "Discount")

                try context.save()
            } 
            completion(true)

        } catch {
            completion(false)
        }

    }
```

I am not able to locate the issue/reason behind it. I am new to Swift and Core Data

Comment: Why not save at the end of the for loop and not each time?

Comment: You should put `try context.save()` after loop ends

Comment: @Larme I tried that as well, still getting the same error/crash

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya that was my initial code, still crashed.. Then i tried this

Comment: Do you have an observer for this notification? "This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification."

Comment: @MikeTaverne As I am new to Swift and can you please tell me what observer is?

Comment: An observer is an object that is listening for ("observing") a particular event. In this case, the event is a change to the NSManagedObjectContext that triggers a notification. From your question, I'm guessing you aren't observing this notification, so the error message would not apply.

Comment: A couple of questions: Does the User_Table entity have any relationships to other entities?  From where is insertUser called?  Is it on the main thread?

Comment: @pbasdf User_Table entity does not have any relationships to other entity, it is called on background thread because this insertUser is called inside a sync functionality(Which sync's and store other datas in other entities).

Comment: @MikeTaverne If i understand the statement correctly, i don't believe there is any observing notification called. And also is "Observer/Observing" similar to NotificationCenter?

Comment: I suspect the problem is because you are on a background thread.  See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html) for details of how to use CoreData on background threads.

Comment: @pbasdf I will look into it thanks... And I suspected that as well, but running in Main Thread doesn't call certain automated functions(like fetching refresh token and access token-using salesforce sdk)-not working